# results[0].formatted_address return undefined or null

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocode

i am trying to get adress by a function where i just have to give latLong but i am with a real problem to save de value  to return or return it simple

```js
function getadress(latLong){
  var adress ="";
  geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
  function(results, status) {
    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if(results[0]) {
        adress = results[0].formatted_address; // wrong way result empty
        alert(results[0].formatted_address); // result perfect adress
        return results[0].formatted_address // result undefiened
      }
      else {
        adress = "No results";
      }
    }
    else {
      adress = status;
    }
  });
  return adress;
}
```

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous. You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback fiction. You need to use the response inside the callback function where/when it is available.

Comment: and how do I get to work

Comment: @geocodezip that's precisely what OP does. They exploit the result of the geocoding in a callback `function(result,status)`. @Alberto you have a typo in your variable `latLong` --> `latLng`

Comment: The `return results[0].formatted_address` is inside the callback function.

Comment: Yes, so? Isn't that how it's supposed to be? Edit : ok I get what you mean. You can't RETURN anything from a callback function, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript being asynchronous, if you write it this way, the returned address will always be empty. Here is the execution order of your current code :

```
function getadress(latLng){

  var adress =""; // (1) Sets address as empty.

  geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng}, // (2) Launches the geocoding request.
      function(results, status) { // (4) later, when the result gets back, populates the address.
          adress = results[0].formatted_address;
      });
  });

  return adress; // (3) Immediately returns an empty address.
}
```

How you should architecture it :

```
function getadress(latLng){

  var adress =""; // (1) Sets address as empty.

  geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng}, // (2) Launches the geocoding request.
      function(results, status) { // (3) later, when the result gets back, populates the address.
          adress = results[0].formatted_address;
          nextStep(address);
      });
  });
}

function nextStep(address){ // (4) should log the address
   console.log(address);
}
```

Comment: Perfect Done ;) tk so much -jeremy :D

Comment: This will also work 'nextStep(results[0].formatted_address);'